Is this the proper way to hang an exterior door?
My contractor's team is building us a new detached garage.
This is how the pre-hung door is attached to the frame.
Is this acceptable? It seems like it could be easily kicked in (which is a real concern in this city).
Is this to code?
What can I suggest to have them improve this before they hang drywall and trim over it?



What, specifically, is concerning to you?

Is this well constructed? Is this to code? What improvements do I need to ask them to do if either of the first two questions is "no"?

Well constructed? Maybe. Did they put a long screw through each hinge into the frame? (They should.) They clearly used long screws at the deadbolt strike. (Good.) Code doesn’t really cover install details afaik. They could improve the install with a can of window and door spray foam. (Glues everything together.) Doors, frankly, can be kicked in most any time. Motion activated lights outside would be one of many ways to protect your stuff.

@AloysiusDefenestrate technically, we can't see how long the strike screws are—we can only see that they went into the OSB jamb a distance equal to the taper on the tip of the screw or more.

Fair comment, @Huesmann, and relatively easy to check. I should have also noted that the reveals and plumb/level should be good before spray foaming.

The limited pics show what appears to be a normal door installation.  If your concern is security, you should have a discussion with the contractor about that and how he may be able to enhance the security of the door.  Be prepared to pay a bit more unless extra security was addressed in your contract.

Thank you all for your feedback. I appreciate the advice!
